# Sagemaker deploy model with inference code and requirements

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I trained a TensorFlow model and now I would like to deploy it. The data needs to be processed thus I have to specify one inference.py script and one requirements.txt file.
When I deploy the model it gives the following error: 
`Failed Reason: The primary container for production variant All Traffic did not pass the ping health check. Please check CloudWatch logs for this endpoint.`  I am not using any VPC and when i try to download a python package from the notebook instance it works without any error. There is a problem with the connection and it can't install the dependecies apparently. What can I do?

```
INFO:__main__:PYTHON SERVICE: True
INFO:__main__:starting services
INFO:__main__:using default model name: model
INFO:__main__:tensorflow serving model config: 
model_config_list: {
  config: {
    name: 'model'
    base_path: '/opt/ml/model'
    model_platform: 'tensorflow'
    model_version_policy: {
      specific: {
        versions: 1
      }
    }
  }
}

INFO:__main__:tensorflow version info:
2021-07-15 14:48:01.085492: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/smprofiler_timeline.cc:460] Initializing the SageMaker Profiler.
2021-07-15 14:48:01.087774: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/smprofiler_timeline.cc:105] SageMaker Profiler is not enabled. The timeline writer thread will not be started, future recorded events will be dropped.
TensorFlow ModelServer: 2.4.0-rc4+dev.sha.no_git
TensorFlow Library: 2.4.1
INFO:__main__:tensorflow serving command: tensorflow_model_server --port=15000 --rest_api_port=15001 --model_config_file=/sagemaker/model-config.cfg --max_num_load_retries=0    
INFO:__main__:started tensorflow serving (pid: 17)
INFO:tfs_utils:Trying to connect with model server: http://localhost:15001/v1/models/model
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=8, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0400b14d90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /v1/models/model
2021-07-15 14:48:01.589503: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/smprofiler_timeline.cc:460] Initializing the SageMaker Profiler.
2021-07-15 14:48:01.589629: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/profiler/internal/smprofiler_timeline.cc:105] SageMaker Profiler is not enabled. The timeline writer thread will not be started, future recorded events will be dropped.
2021-07-15 14:48:01.596877: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:464] Adding/updating models.
2021-07-15 14:48:01.596910: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server_core.cc:587]  (Re-)adding model: model
2021-07-15 14:48:01.698159: I tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:46] Retrying of Reserving resources for servable: {name: model version: 1} exhausted max_num_retries: 0
2021-07-15 14:48:01.698222: I tensorflow_serving/core/basic_manager.cc:740] Successfully reserved resources to load servable {name: model version: 1}
2021-07-15 14:48:01.698242: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:66] Approving load for servable version {name: model version: 1}
2021-07-15 14:48:01.698259: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:74] Loading servable version {name: model version: 1}
2021-07-15 14:48:01.698325: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:32] Reading SavedModel from: /opt/ml/model/000000001
2021-07-15 14:48:01.716135: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:55] Reading meta graph with tags { serve }
2021-07-15 14:48:01.716197: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/reader.cc:93] Reading SavedModel debug info (if present) from: /opt/ml/model/000000001
2021-07-15 14:48:01.720153: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 4. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=7, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0400b29450>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /v1/models/model
2021-07-15 14:48:01.825477: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:206] Restoring SavedModel bundle.
2021-07-15 14:48:01.833263: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2300060000 Hz
2021-07-15 14:48:01.971809: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:190] Running initialization op on SavedModel bundle at path: /opt/ml/model/000000001
2021-07-15 14:48:01.989851: I external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.cc:277] SavedModel load for tags { serve }; Status: success: OK. Took 291516 microseconds.
2021-07-15 14:48:01.992763: I tensorflow_serving/servables/tensorflow/saved_model_warmup_util.cc:59] No warmup data file found at /opt/ml/model/000000001/assets.extra/tf_serving_warmup_requests
2021-07-15 14:48:01.994208: I tensorflow_serving/util/retrier.cc:46] Retrying of Loading servable: {name: model version: 1} exhausted max_num_retries: 0
2021-07-15 14:48:01.994232: I tensorflow_serving/core/loader_harness.cc:87] Successfully loaded servable version {name: model version: 1}
2021-07-15 14:48:02.003695: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:371] Running gRPC ModelServer at 0.0.0.0:15000 ...
[warn] getaddrinfo: address family for nodename not supported
2021-07-15 14:48:02.006269: I tensorflow_serving/model_servers/server.cc:391] Exporting HTTP/REST API at:localhost:15001 ...
[evhttp_server.cc : 238] NET_LOG: Entering the event loop ...
WARNING:urllib3.connectionpool:Retrying (Retry(total=6, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0400b29a10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')': /v1/models/model
INFO:tfs_utils:<Response [200]>
INFO:tfs_utils:model: http://localhost:15001/v1/models/model is available now
INFO:__main__:nginx config: 
load_module modules/ngx_http_js_module.so;
worker_processes auto;
daemon off;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;
error_log  /dev/stderr error;
worker_rlimit_nofile 4096;
events {
  worker_connections 2048;
}
http {
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/json;
  access_log /dev/stdout combined;
  js_include tensorflow-serving.js;

  upstream tfs_upstream {
    server localhost:15001;
  }

  upstream gunicorn_upstream {
    server unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=1;
  }

  server {
    listen 8080 deferred;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    client_body_buffer_size 100m;
    subrequest_output_buffer_size 100m;

    set $tfs_version 2.4;
    set $default_tfs_model model;

    location /tfs {
        rewrite ^/tfs/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass_request_headers off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Type 'application/json';
        proxy_set_header Accept 'application/json';
        proxy_pass http://tfs_upstream;
    }

    location /ping {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_upstream/ping;
    }

    location /invocations {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_upstream/invocations;
    }

    location /models {
        proxy_pass http://gunicorn_upstream/models;
    }

    location / {
        return 404 '{"error": "Not Found"}';
    }

    keepalive_timeout 3;
  }
}

INFO:__main__:gunicorn command: gunicorn -b unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock -k gevent --chdir /sagemaker --workers 1 --threads 1 --pythonpath /opt/ml/model/code,/opt/ml/model/code/lib -e TFS_GRPC_PORT_RANGE=15000-15002 -e TFS_REST_PORT_RANGE=15001-15003 -e SAGEMAKER_MULTI_MODEL=False -e SAGEMAKER_SAFE_PORT_RANGE=15000-15999 -e SAGEMAKER_TFS_WAIT_TIME_SECONDS=300 python_service:app
INFO:__main__:gunicorn version info:
gunicorn (version 20.0.4)
INFO:__main__:started gunicorn (pid: 72)
[2021-07-15 14:48:02 +0000] [72] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2021-07-15 14:48:02 +0000] [72] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock (72)
INFO:__main__:gunicorn server is ready!
[2021-07-15 14:48:02 +0000] [72] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2021-07-15 14:48:02 +0000] [76] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 76
INFO:__main__:nginx version info:
nginx version: nginx/1.20.0
built by gcc 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.20.0/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.20.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
INFO:__main__:started nginx (pid: 77)
INFO:python_service:Creating grpc channel for port: 15000
[2021-07-15 14:48:03 +0000] [76] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 162, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 414, in <module>
    resources = ServiceResources()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 400, in __init__
    self._python_service_resource = PythonServiceResource()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 83, in __init__
    self._handler, self._input_handler, self._output_handler = self._import_handlers()
  File "/sagemaker/python_service.py", line 278, in _import_handlers
    spec.loader.exec_module(inference)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/opt/ml/model/code/inference.py", line 1, in <module>
    import librosa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'librosa'
[2021-07-15 14:48:03 +0000] [76] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 76)
[2021-07-15 14:48:03 +0000] [72] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2021-07-15 14:48:03 +0000] [72] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

The code I used is this:

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow.serving import Model
model = Model(entry_point='inference.py',
                        dependencies=['requirements.txt'],
                        model_data=bucket,
                       role=role,
                       sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
                       framework_version='2.4.1')
predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type="ml.m4.xlarge")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already trained your model outside of SageMaker you want to focus on just deployment/inference. Thus, you want to store your model artifacts in S3 in a tar.gz format. The correct api call that you want to be working with is the following code block.

```
from sagemaker.tensorflow import TensorFlowModel

model = TensorFlowModel(model_data='s3://mybucket/model.tar.gz', role='MySageMakerRole')

predictor = model.deploy(initial_instance_count=1, instance_type='ml.c5.xlarge')
```

Check out more information at the following link
https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/using_tf.html#deploy-tensorflow-serving-models

For preprocessing there are two approaches you can take.

1. Have your data preprocessing done in the SageMaker notebook and then invoke the endpoint that you have created with your formatted data.
2. Take the TensorFlow container and adjust it for your own use case. This follows an example known as "Bring Your Own Model". Everything in SageMaker is Dockerized and to bring your own inference code/logic you want to follow the container structure SageMaker has. Here is an end to end example of bringing a TensorFlow model to SageMaker for training and/or deployment.

https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_bring_your_own

I work for AWS & my opinions are my own